# Storing values in an array using shell scripting

Tags: shell, unix, quoting

This works fine since because i'm directly inputting the data.

```
declare -a arr
arr=( $(awk '/123456789/{print NR}' filename) )
echo ${arr[0]}
echo ${arr[*]}
```

Bt when i do as below, it doesn't work. Can u let me know how the parameter 'name' can be used in the command below :

```
echo  Enter your search string:  
read name
declare -a arr
arr=( $(awk '/"$name"/{print NR}' filename )
echo ${arr[0]}
echo ${arr[*]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments I am posting this answer. This is the script that will work for you:

```
read -e -p "Enter your search string: " name
#echo "name: [$name]"
declare -a arr
arr=( $(awk /"$name"'/{print NR}' x ) )
echo ${arr[0]}
echo ${arr[*]}
```

Comment: @ Anubhava : Thank U. Your comments and modifications in the script are very helpful But what's wrong in the above script ?

Comment: @JackieJames: Sorry to respond late, I think you've figured it out that your script had one missing right parenthesis `)` in awk command.

Comment: @ Anubhava : No, not paranthesis it's misplace of single quote. arr=( $(awk /"$name"'/{print NR}' x ) ) correct 

arr=( $(awk /"$name"/'{print NR}' filename ) misplace of single quote

Comment: @ Anubhava : Can you please look into this 'Is it possible to write the below code in shell script?' This is another different post.

Comment: @ Anubhava : Can u please check the post by title "Is it possible to write the below code in shell script?"

Comment: Sure I will check and try to answer that.

Comment: I couldn't fine `Is it possible to write the below code in shell script` under your questions links, is it possible for you to provide me a link of that question.

Comment: @ Anubhava : I deleted that post. Can u plzz try this 'How to include variables in the sed command?'

Answer (score 1):

```
arr=( $(awk /"$name"/'{print NR}' filename ) )
```

Comment: echo  enter the string to be searched :  
read name
declare -a arr
arr=( $(awk /"$name"/'{print NR}' filename )
echo ${arr[0]}
echo ${arr[*]}

Output :

enter the string to be searched :
123456789
./newarray.sh: line 4: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'

Comment: @ Jens : Your command is right but there is a misplace of single quote.

arr=( $(awk /"$name"'/{print NR}' filename ) )

Thank U, Anubhava :)

Comment: No, there's no misplacement. There are no spaces around the / so the shell parses `/"$name"/'{print NR}'` as one token.